# Subgradient of multi-class hinge loss

Tags: gradient-descent, hinge-loss

Let the multi-class hinge loss be given by:

$$ L(\Theta,(x,y)) = \max_{j \neq y} \Big[ 1+ \sum_{i=1}^{d} x_i(\Theta_{ij} - \Theta_{iy}) \Big]_{+}  $$

$$ = \max_{j \neq y} \Big[ 1+ \langle x, \Theta_{\cdot j} - \Theta_{\cdot y} \rangle \Big]_{+} $$

where $\Theta \in \mathbb{R}^{d \times K}$ is the classifier, $x \in \mathbb{R}^d $ is a classifer vector and $ y \in K$ is the lable. The empirical loss function is given by $$R^{\text{emp}}(\Theta) = \frac{1}{n} \sum_{k=1}^{n} L(\Theta, (x_k,y_k)).$$

For a given pair $(x,y)$, what is the subgradient $G$ of $R^{\text{emp}}(\Theta) $?

The problem seems quite simular to this [answer](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/172869). Implementing this, the subgradient would then be,
for a given pair $(x,y)$ and $j$,

if $\langle x, \Theta_{\cdot j} - \Theta_{\cdot y} \rangle + 1 > 0 $, $G_{\cdot j} = x, G_{\cdot y} = -x, $ and $G_{\cdot i} = 0$ for all $ i \neq j, y$.

if $\langle x, \Theta_{\cdot j} - \Theta_{\cdot y} \rangle + 1 < 0 $, $G = \bar{0}$ is a zero matrix.

Elif,  $\langle x, \Theta_{\cdot j} - \Theta_{\cdot y} \rangle + 1 = 0 $,  $G_{\cdot j} = \alpha x, G_{\cdot y} = - \alpha x, $ and $G_{\cdot i} = 0$ for all $ i \neq j, y$ and some $\alpha \in [0,1]$.